# Delete an unused Label using the java api?

Tags: java, neo4j

Is there anyway to delete an unused `Label` via the java API?

Apparently, unused Labels are not automatically deleted.

The javadoc for `org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations.getAllLabels()` says:

> However, it may also return more than that (e.g. it can return "historic" labels that are no longer used).

For example, if you create an `Index` and then drop it, the `Label` remains.

Comment: What is your goal here?

Comment: Nothing in particular, just how to maintain a clean database.  I'm considering migrating a number of datasets to neo4j and am thinking about long term management issues.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no clean way to delete unused labels.

Of course you can use batch inserter API to create a duplicate of your datastore. This duplicate will not have the unused labels any more. See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

I create a tool that has a store-copy functionality and does what Stefan said.

You can also skip properties or relationships with it:

https://github.com/jexp/store-utils/tree/20#store-copy